# How do I get mercurial to show the diff during `hg com`?

Tags: mercurial, diff

Is there a way to configure `hg com` so that in the commit message file that pops up in the external editor, instead of just showing which files were changed (in the `HG:` lines) it actually shows the full diff?  I'd rather view the output and compose my commit message simultaneously from the comfort of my text editor as opposed to doing `hg diff` on the command line separately beforehand.

Comment: just to add to the question: OP is looking for an equivalent to `$ git commit -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) does this out of the box: a top panel for the commit message and below that, a left pane listing the affected files and a right pane showing the diffs, one after the other.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2016, it's possible to do this with the `committemplate` configuration option. Adding the following to an `hgrc` file will include the diff in the editor window inline as you type your commit message.

```
[committemplate]
changeset = {desc}\n\n
    HG: {extramsg}
    HG: user: {author}\n{ifeq(p2rev, "-1", "",
   "HG: branch merge\n")
   }HG: branch '{branch}'\n{if(currentbookmark,
   "HG: bookmark '{currentbookmark}'\n")  }{subrepos %
   "HG: subrepo {subrepo}\n"              }
   {splitlines(diff()) % 'HG: {line}\n'}
```

See `hg help hgrc` and search for `committemplate` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial doesn't have that as a built-in feature, but it's easy to simulate in your editor (as launched by commit).

Here's an example using VIM: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/DiffsInCommitMessageInVIM

The hgeditor script https://www.mercurial-scm.org/hg/hg-stable/raw-file/tip/hgeditor provides further examples.

The basic jist is:

1. at editor launch run `hg diff` redirecting to a temp file
2. have your editor load both the commit message file and the diff