# Vim - show diff on commit in mercurial;

Tags: vim, mercurial, diff, hook, commit

In my `.hgrc` I can provide an editor or a command to launch an editor with options on commit.

I want to write a method or alias that launches `$ hg ci`, it would not only open up message in Vim, but also would split window and there print out `$ hg diff`.

I know that I can give parameters to vim by using `+{command}` option. So launching `$ vim "+vsplit"` does the split but any other options goes to first opened window. So I assume i need a specific function, yet I have no experience in writing my own Vim scripts.

The script should:

- Open new vertical split with empty buffer (with `vnew` possibly)
- In empty buffer launch `:.!hg diff`
- Set empty buffer file type as diff `:set ft=diff`

I've written such function:

```
function! HgCiDiff()
    vnew
    :.!hg diff
    set ft=diff
endfunction
```

And in `.hgrc` I've added option: `editor = vim "+HgCiDiff()"`

It kind of works, but I would like that splited window would be in right side (now it opens up in left) and mercurial message would be focused window. Also `:wq` could be setted as temporary shortcut to `:wq<CR>:q!` (having an assumption that mercurial message is is focused).

Any suggestions to make this a bit more useful and less chunky?

**UPDATE:** I found [vim split guide](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/vim-splits-a-guide-to-doing-exactly-what-you-want/) so changing `vnew` with `rightbelow vnew` opens up diff on the right side.

Comment: You may want to do something like `silent! setlocal ft=diff previewwindow bufhidden=delete nobackup noswf nobuflisted nowrap buftype=nofile` instead of just `set ft=diff` (taken from `~/.vim/ftplugin/svn.vim`).  Also it would be nicer to have it run whenever you edit a file that matches `/tmp/hg-editor-*.txt`, i.e. set it up as an autocommand.

Comment: ah I did not knew that you can nest set parameters in such manner. neat.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683226/how-do-i-get-mercurial-to-show-the-diff-during-hg-com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I expanded my own code:

```
function! HgCiDiff()
    "In .hgrc editor option I call vim "+HgCiDiff()"
    "It opens new split with diff inside
    rightbelow  vnew
    :.!hg diff
    set ft=diff
    saveas! /tmp/hgdiff.txt
    execute "normal \<c-w>w"
endfunction
```

Yet It missed `:wq` mapping as `:wqa`, yet using `:wqa` is not that hard.

Sources of my vimrc is located here: http://hg.jackleo.info/vim-configs/src/08df5cb9d143/vimrc
Sources of my hgrc is located here: http://hg.jackleo.info/home-configs/src/22f5fb47a7d2/.hgrc

**Update:** as suggested by Randy Morris I updated my code and now it works just as I wanted. Thanks! Also added few extra features as the time went by.

```
function! HgCiDiff()
    "In .hgrc editor option I call vim "+HgCiDiff()"
    "It opens new split with diff inside
    rightbelow  vnew
    setlocal buftype=nofile
    :.!hg diff
    setlocal ft=diff
    wincmd p
    setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
    cnoremap wq wqa
    cnoremap q qa
    start
endfunction
```

Comment: Couple of comments:  1) The last line can be changed to "wincmd w" or more correctly, "wincmd p", either will work.  2) You probably want to use "setlocal" instead of just "set" for the filetype.  3) Unless you explicitly want to save the diff to /tmp/hgdiff.txt, you could instead "setlocal buftype=nofile".

Comment: And 4) You could add a "cnoremap wq wqa" to achieve that last goal. (couldn't edit previous comment)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

Hmm I think this might not be what you are after on second reading. I understand you want a multi-file (unified) diff. I'd really use a hg-aware UI tool and a separate vim editor for the commit message. Sorry about that.

I'll leave the 'original' response stand in case you didn't know VCSCommand + Hg + Vim yet:

My weapon of choice is to abstract it all away with

#### [vcscommand.vim : CVS/SVN/SVK/git/hg/bzr integration plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90)

You would

```
:VCSVimDiff
```

to diffsplit against the repo version (also with <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>)

```
:VCSVimDiff <revid>
```

to compare against a specific revision.

Comment: Thanks, no I haven't knew about VCSCommand, it is a great tool, yet you are right. It's not what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution consists of three vim files.  It doesn't require hg configuration changes, and only shows the diff for the files you're committing, if you've used `hg commit file1 file2`:

**~/.vim/ftdetect/hg.vim**

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile /tmp/hg-editor-*.txt set filetype=hg
```

**~/.vim/syntax/hg.vim**

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: hg commit file
" Maintainer:   Marius Gedminas <marius@gedmin.as>
" Filenames:    /tmp/hg-editor-*.txt
" Last Change:  2012 July 8

" Based on gitcommit.vim by Tim Pope

if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

syn case match
syn sync minlines=50

if has("spell")
  syn spell toplevel
endif

syn match   hgComment   "^HG: .*"

hi def link hgComment       Comment

let b:current_syntax = "hg"
```

**~/.vim/ftplugin/hg.vim**

```
" Show diff while editing a Mercurial commit message
" Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009333/vim-show-diff-on-commit-in-mercurial
" and Michael Scherer' svn.vim

function! HgCiDiff()
    let i = 0
    let list_of_files = ''

    while i <= line('$') && getline(i) != 'HG: --'
        let i = i + 1
    endwhile
    while i <= line('$')
        let line = getline(i)
        if line =~ '^HG: \(added\|changed\)'
            let file = substitute(line, '^HG: \(added\|changed\) ', '', '')
            let file = "'".substitute(file, "'", "'\''", '')."'"
            let list_of_files = list_of_files . ' '.file
        endif
        let i = i + 1
    endwhile

    if list_of_files == ""
        return
    endif

    pclose
    new
    setlocal ft=diff previewwindow bufhidden=delete nobackup noswf nobuflisted nowrap buftype=nofile
    silent exec ':0r!hg diff ' . list_of_files
    setlocal nomodifiable
    goto 1
    redraw!
    " nooo idea why I have to do this
    syn enable
endfunction

call HgCiDiff()
```

Comment: The first version had a horrible bug where it assumed hg would ignore everything after the 'HG:' comment block and included the diff directly in the same buffer (like git commit -v does).  This made hg include the entire diff inside the commit message.  Oops.

Comment: With some additions I can see myself using this :) one of those would be spellchecker setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
Also updated my own code snipped with few additional fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my variation based on Marius Gedminas and JackLeo's versions:

```
function! HgCiDiff()
    " find files that were changed (not interested in added or deleted)
    let changed_files = []
    let pattern = '\vHG: changed \zs(.+)\ze'
    while search("HG: changed", "W") > 0
        let line_text = getline(line("."))
        call add(changed_files, matchstr(line_text, pattern))
    endwhile
    let diff_cmd = "hg diff " . join(changed_files, " ")
    " Reset cursor to beginning of the buffer
    call cursor(1, 1)
    rightbelow vnew
    setlocal buftype=nofile
    let diff_output = system(diff_cmd)
    call append(0, split(diff_output, "\n"))
    " Reset cursor to beginning of the buffer
    call cursor(1, 1)
    setlocal ft=diff
    wincmd p
    setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
    cnoremap wq wqa
    cnoremap q qa!
    startinsert
endfunction
```