# how to get subversion to show the diff during 'svn ci'?

Tags: svn

Basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683226/how-do-i-get-mercurial-to-show-the-diff-during-hg-com) but for subversion.

I am tired of missing a file or adding too many changes.

I doubt it matters, but I am using Emacs as my editor.

Comment: What's wrong with typing `svn diff` first to check what you're committing?

Comment: @Ben I like to make small commits of only some of the files I have changed. Two commands means that I might miss a directory for either of the commands.

In addition, I might forget the svn diff command.

Answer (score 1):

The subversion package contains the elisp module *psvn* - a subversion interface for emacs. You can start it with `M-x` `svn-status`. Mark the to be committed files with `m` and start the commit with `c`.

If you want to see the complete diff when entering the commit message, set the emacs variable `svn-log-edit-show-diff-for-commit` to `t`.